# Heroku error on DB column

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have a rails app with a column called `cancel`

I have 2 migrations for this as I changed it from a `string` to a `boolean`

This migrations runs first:

```
class AddCancelToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :cancel, :string
  end
end
```

Then this:

```
class Changetype < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    change_column :users, :cancel, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

Everything works fine locally, but as im trying to push to heroku, im getting this error message.

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "cancel" cannot be cast automatically to type boolean
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING cancel::boolean".
: ALTER TABLE "users" ALTER COLUMN "cancel" TYPE boolean
```

Any idea how to overcome this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def change
    change_column :users, :cancel, :boolean, default: false
end
```

should instead be:

```
def
 change_column :users, :cancel, 'boolean USING CAST(cancel AS boolean)'
end
```